# How to Resize Different Types of file on core php

Tags: php, dropzone

I am trying Different types of file upload to resize but not working. 
I use dropzone in file uploaded.

===> Form Code in Page

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone"></form>
```

===> upload.php file

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){
include 'connection.php';

$targetDir = "documents/";
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile)){
    //insert file information into db table
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded) VALUES('".$fileName."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");
}

}
```

how can i resize file after uploaded?

Comment: Have a look at Image Magick: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: not only single image uploaded. single time .pdf,.doc,image any files are uploaded.

Comment: There isn't a clear cut way of doing this unless you use file compression http://php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php . But you'll have to uncompress again them when you want to use them, potentially creating a lot of overhead on your server.